# Facebook App - Server not found error

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I have created a facebook app and url is https://apps.facebook.com/wishisdone/?fb_source=bookmark_favorites. When I view the app it says server not found. My website's url is http://wishisdone.visionswebsites.com/wishisdone/login.aspx.

But facebook app is redirecting to www.wishisdone.visionswebsites.com It should open without www but there is no app setting in the facebook to include or exclude www. I entered the correct url "http://wishisdone.visionswebsites.com/wishisdone/login.aspx" in the **site url**

Please help me. How can I make it working.

[image]

Comment: What exactly did you enter as address for Canvas App?

Comment: "https://wishisdone.visionswebsites.com/wishisdone/login.aspx" with https

Comment: The POST request from Facebook goes to the right address, but I’m getting different error message: _“The connection to wishisdone.visionswebsites.com was interrupted while the page was loading.”_

Comment: And calling https://wishisdone.visionswebsites.com/ in my browser directly leads to the same error message, where as the non-HTTPS version answers fine. So it seems there is something wrong with your SSL setup.

Comment: Website should have ssl certificate to create facebook app? Currently we dont have ssl. Please clarify?

Comment: Yes, of course it should. (If Facebook were to allow apps to be called via HTTP while facebook.com itself is accessed via HTTPS, browsers would block anything inside the iframe as insecure content.)